# Angular application for Desktop/ios/android

Tags: angular, cordova, web, phonegap

I have to develop a responsive website in angular and server side of the REST API. I also have to deploy it on the Android and iOS stores. My question: is it possible to package my angular application with Cordova / phonegap easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single application for Android , ios and web is possible in latest ionic3.

> Ionic 3 supports hybrid mobile apps for Android , iOS , windows too
>
> Ionic 3 supports Progressive web apps too.

Comment: I want to have the same code for my angular application for Firefox / chrome / iOS / Android. Ionic is exclusively oriented for mobile

Comment: Ionic3 using Angular4 and supports most of the browsers as web apps find the link https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/?hl=en

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll look ionic, community seems important. And Google seems to push the PWA more and more.